# Apache camel disruptor component

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to set up a netty based TCP server which can process multiple requests in a single connection. I am using disruptor and a delay of 5 seconds in myHandler to test. My route is,

```
this.from("netty4:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=true&synchronous=false&encoder=#myEncoder&decoder=#myDecoder").to("disruptor:myDisruptor"); 

this.from("disruptor:myDisruptor?concurrentConsumers=20").to("bean:myHandler");
```

My transactions are processed sequentially even after having concurrentConsumers=20 on disruptor. What might be the reason ? How can i make message handler asynchronous ? The below route works for me,

```
this.from("netty4:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=true&synchronous=false&encoder=#myEncoder&decoder=#myDecoder").threads(20).to("bean:myHandler");
```

Comment: Are you sure your 'handler' is not synchronized ? with a basic example, it works as expected.

Comment: @JérémieB - my handler is not synchronized. Could you please share your basic example.

Comment: It was exactly yours, without the class you didn't provide: #encoder, #decoder and myHandler : I have only printed the threadid